# Cannot display Unicode Characters (like λ) in PDF output of Jupyter

Tags: pdf, unicode, jupyter-notebook, julia, mathematical-expressions

I'm using Julia in a `jupyter notebook`.

I want to generate a pdf for the results of my work. However, when generating the pdf, the `λ` of the mathematical expression `λ=3` is lost so that the output in the pdf is `=3`.

Here is the jupyter notebook code

```
In[1]: λ=3 
Out[1]: 3
```

Here is the pdf generated with the jupyter notebook

```
In[1]: =3 
Out[1]: 3
```

This is not the case in with the pdf generated with `nteract` where the expression `λ=3` is fully printed out. However the overall appearance of the pdf generated with `nteract` is not as nice as the pdf generated with `jupyter notebook`.

Here is printed pdf generated with `nteract` (looks exactly the same as the code itself):

```
In[1]: λ=3
Out[1]: 3
```

Can somebody know how to print such character with `jupyter notebook`?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Some minimal code to reproduce would help.

Comment: I tried the accepted answer, unfortunately it didn't work for me. Then I found a way to kind of skip this issue by using `$\lambda$` this kind of notation, luckily it did work for me. So, in short, don't use unicode letters, but reply on latex syntax to generate Greek letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is related to how Jupyter itself generates and compiles the latex file. Jupyter, by default, compiles the file with `xelatex` to support Unicode. **My guess** is, however, `xelatex` requires some configurations in the files and Jupyter does not generate the file that works out of the box with plain `xelatex` command.

You can change the configuration of Jupyter to compile latex file generated with `pdflatex` or `latex` command.

**Solution:**
Find your Jupyter configuration directory(i.e. output of `jupyter --config-dir`, on Linux usually `~/.jupyter`. To find out which jupyter IJulia uses run `using IJulia; IJulia.jupyter` then find out the config directory of that jupyter)

Create the file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in this directory if there is not one, already.

Put the following line of code at the end of this file and save it:

```
c.PDFExporter.latex_command = ['pdflatex', '{filename}']
```

Then you can export the PDF file using the notebook, as usual. The characters should appear, just right. This should work provided that `pdflatex` command is found in your shell.

If you do not have `pdflatex` but have `latex` you can also use the following line instead of the code above:

```
c.PDFExporter.latex_command = ['latex', '--output-format=pdf', '{filename}']
```

---

**If you are not able to change the configuration of Jupyter**, download the latex file and compile it with the command `latex --output-format=pdf filename.tex`.

Hope it works!

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me, I get errors like "! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 12479 = U+30BF,"

Comment: ['pdflatex', '{filename}']

Comment: The problem might be related with your Latex distribution. Could you try `pdflatex` with the Latex copy of your notebook (Download as *.tex)?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is ugly, and I will get to it below, but first it is important to understand why this is happening.

### Why is this happening

The intermediate `.tex` file that is generated indirectly calls for the Latin Modern fonts. Latin Modern is a fine choice for math fonts, but it is sucky for monospaced. The Latin Modern mono font does not include Greek.

Latin Modern is set by the [unicode-math](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) LaTeX package, which is loaded in the generated LaTeX around line 43.

```
    \ifPDFTeX
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \IfFileExists{alphabeta.sty}{
              \usepackage{alphabeta}
          }{
              \usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
              \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
          }
    \else
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \fi
```

So the `unicode-math` package will be loaded if you are using XeLaTeX (which is a good default) or LuaTeX or any other LaTeX engine for which `fontspec` is available.

The unicode-math package very reasonably uses Latin Modern for math, but if nothing is set otherwise, it will also use Latin Modern for monospaced fonts. From the documentation

> Once the package is loaded, traditional TFM-based maths fonts are no longer supported; you can only switch to a different OpenType maths font using the \setmathfont command. If you do not load an OpenType maths font before \begin{document}, Latin Modern Math will be loaded automatically.

The creators of `unicode-math` assume that you will set your non-math fonts up after you have loaded the `unicode-math`, but that isn't done with the `.tex` generated by `jupyter nbconvert`. (I don't know if this is a jupyter thing or a Pandoc thing, but either way we end up with a document that is used Latin Modern for more than just math.)

So one solution is to set some other mono font after unicode-math is loaded and before `\begin{Document}`.

### My solution

My solution is tuned for what I already had set up. It may not be the right approach for you, and it certainly will need some adjusting.

My Makefile used to have a simple `juypter nbconvert --to=pdf` in it. But now I need to edit the intermediate `.tex` file. So I have this for a notebook named `computation-examples`. You will need to use your own file name or do some Make rule magic.

```
# sed on macOS is just weird. Resorting to perl
computation-examples.tex: computation-examples.ipynb
    jupyter nbconvert --to=latex $<
    perl -pi -e '/^([ \t]*)\\usepackage{unicode-math}/ and $$_.="$$1\\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}\n"' $@
```

The perl adds the line `\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}` immediately after the line with`\usepackage{unicode-math}`. There are probably nicer ways to do that. I started with sed, but gave up. So the `.tex` file that is then processed to PDF by XeLaTeX has this.

```latex
    \else
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \usepackage{unicode-math}
        \usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
    \fi
```

The `fontsetup` package preserves all of the goodness of `unicode-math` while setting up the non-math founts. The default is to use the OpenType (`.otf`) Computer Modern Unicode fonts that will be a part of any TeX distribution that has xelatex on it.

### Another approach

Probably a cleaner approach, but one I haven't experimented with, would be to create a fontspec.cfg file which lies about (overrides) what font files to load for what we are calling Latin Modern Mono. I would need to reread the [fontspec documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) for the hundredths time to do that.

### Make magic

Since writing the above, I have set up a more general Makefile rule,

```
%.tex: %.ipynb
    jupyter nbconvert --to=latex $<
    perl -pi -e '/^([ \t]*)\\usepackage{unicode-math}/ and $$_.="$$1\\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}\n"' $@
```

which sits along rules to make a PDF from a `.tex` file.

But if you aren't using make and Makefiles, then you can wrap up that perl monstrosity into a script of your choosing.