# Greek letters don't output in PDF

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am attempting to export to PDF a Jupyter notebook containing Greek letters, however, the exported PDF doesn't render the characters.

I have tried using, direct input (actually typing the characters in text), unicode u"\u03B8", and the syntax "\N{greek small letter theta}". All show the correct output in the Jupyter notebook after running the cell but neither appear in the exported PDF. I've tried multiple different characters and none of them show.

Don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using the jupyter/scipy-notebook running in Docker Toolbox.

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have tried? This would be helpful to trying to diagnose this issue.

Comment: It's literally just print(<Greek character>), using the methods I mentioned above. Not sure if anything else is relevant, but if it is let me know and I'll add it when I have a chance

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and (ugly) solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73073900/1304076 The problem is that the generated `.tex` calls for Latin Modern Math, which doesn't have Greek in its mono variety.