# Jupyter 'save as pdf' doesn't show non-latin letters in output and comments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How to save as pdf jupyter files with non-latin symbols?
For example, I've got

```
print('היי!')
```

In pdf, I will have only *print('   !')*
I've seen that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581442/cannot-display-unicode-characters-like-%CE%BB-in-pdf-output-of-jupyter), but nothing has changed after suggested solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot display Unicode Characters (like λ) in PDF output of Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581442/cannot-display-unicode-characters-like-%ce%bb-in-pdf-output-of-jupyter)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. Moreover, that made impossible to download any pdf file: 500 : Internal Server Error.

Comment: I've already deleted that code from config, but still cannot save file as pdf at all. Nothing works now.